# Can I reuse / re-import fluid cache files into Blender?

Tags: import, fluid-simulation, cache, mantaflow

While making multiple fluid simulations I had saved multiple cache folders with the "data" and "config" folders. Is there a way that I can reuse the cached data to import back the old liquid simulation?

I have already done .abc (Alembic) exports of my simulations, but I would need to access to original data in order to tweak some parameters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple cache folders, if you scroll down in your fluid Domain properties and open *Cache,* you will be able to select a specific cache folder (Cache folders usually have the word *cache* in them as you can already see In your image).

[image]

Comment: Just adding the path to the folder in the cache properties does not load the previously baked simulation contained in that folder...